# How to display previous epochs in of NLCD on GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, nlcd

GEE has the full National Land Cover Database and this has enabled a number of projects for me but I'm stumbling on a simple problem.

When I display the NLCD I can see that each point contains land cover values of all four epochs (1992, 2001, 2006 and 2011) but I'm not sure how to display them. As of now I basically just have the default display code but I'd like to show both 2011 and 2006.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USGS/NLCD');
var landcover = dataset.select('landcover');
var landcoverVis = {
  min: 11.0,
  max: 95.0,
  palette: [
    '5475A8', 'ffffff', 'E8D1D1', 'E29E8C', 'ff0000', 'B50000', 'D2CDC0',
    '85C77E', '38814E', 'D4E7B0', 'AF963C', 'DCCA8F', 'FDE9AA', 'D1D182',
    'A3CC51', '82BA9E', 'FBF65D', 'CA9146', 'C8E6F8', '64B3D5'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(-76.356, 35.286, 8);
Map.addLayer(landcover, landcoverVis, 'Landcover');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add them all to the map, you can filter them for example by their system:index property and add them individually as images to the map.

```
// load the four maps based on their year
var years = ['1992','2001', '2006', '2011'];

Map.setCenter(-76.356, 35.286, 8);
for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  var year = years[i];
  var nameImage = 'NLCD' + year;

  Map.addLayer(landcover.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', nameImage)).first(), landcoverVis, 'Landcover: '+year);
}
```

You could also write down the filter four times with the name of the image ID written for each element, off course.